# gets breaks the cycle on C

Tags: c, gets

I'm trying to use **gets** to store a name/little phrase

It was supposed to hold 39 chars, but after I enter the first char it returns to the previous cycle. ( I have a Do While showing content on the main)

Why doesn't it work as supposed?

```
char nome[40];
printf("\nNome do Equipamento: ");
gets(nome);
strcpy(eq[n].nomeEquipamento, nome);
```

Comment: To first get the obligatory out of the way: `gets` is _evil_. And not even `goto` kinda evil. It's evil in the sense of "don't ever, ever use it, no matter what the circumstances". It's essentially a walking security vulnerability.

Now that that's out of the way - please show us the rest of the main function, can't tell anything from this.

Comment: There is no longer a function in the C language called gets, it was removed 2 years ago.

Comment: @Pedro Please post the full code.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both and I have the same problem still. what do you mean by uninitialized variable? @AlterMann

Comment: @Cubic mind taking a look over the whole thing? http://pastebin.com/2PL8s4Re you can replicate the same by pressing: 1 2 1 2 2 x

Comment: don't press enter after the first character, enter the whole string and then press enter. Please note `gets`  reads characters from standard input until a new line is found.

Comment: maybe one should mention the better alternative to gets() and that is fgets()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you have provided, there is a `scanf` call before `gets`

```
printf("\nCodigo do Equipamento: ");    
scanf("%d",&codigo);     
eq[n].codDipositivo=codigo;
printf("\nNome do Equipamento: ");              
gets(nome);
```

The `scanf` call leaves behind `\n` character after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This `\n` character is read by `gets` and that's why you are facing this problem.
To consume this `\n`, use a `getchar` starement just after the `scanf`;

```
 printf("\nCodigo do Equipamento: ");    
 scanf("%d",&codigo);
 getchar();      // To comsume '\n'      
 eq[n].codDipositivo=codigo;
 printf("\nNome do Equipamento: ");              
 gets(nome);
```

Now about `gets`; Happy to sat that **the evil `gets` is a history now**. Use `fgets` instead.
And also do not use `strcpy`, instead you can use [`strncpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strncpy.html) (before using it, read the prrovided link carefully).

Comment: thank you so much! I've added fflush(stdin); before the scanf and fgets and it works now!

Comment: @Pedro; Do not use `fflush(stdin)`. It invokes **umdefined behavior** if you are not on MS-DOS.

Comment: You should always mention the flaws in `strncpy` before suggesting to use it. Otherwise you are only switching one vulnerability to another.

Comment: @user694733; True. Added a link for that.

Comment: @user694733 Really, standard C strings are broken. I'm not sure if this is a common practice, but first thing I do in a new project (if I get to make the calls) is to replace all instances of c strings with a decent string library.

Comment: @Cubic I agree that C strings are broken. I usually have a collection of string functions which use standard functions behind the scenes. Problem with string libraries is that there is no standard string type. In addition, many string libraries require heap to function which is a problem in some embedded devices.